# Can I keep Outlook 2007 from adding my name to recipient list when replying to all?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

This question is **not** a duplicate of this one:

[Can I always exclude specific recipient from Reply All?](https://superuser.com/questions/408674/can-i-always-exclude-specific-recipient-from-reply-all)

Or these which are about Outlook 2010 and are actually different issues:

[reply-to-all includes my name in the TO line](https://superuser.com/questions/203591/reply-to-all-includes-my-name-in-the-to-line)
[Stop sending mail to myself when choosing Reply All in Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/155241/stop-sending-mail-to-myself-when-choosing-reply-all-in-outlook)

**Onto the Question**

When I reply to all in Outlook 2007, it adds my name to the recipient list, so I end up getting the email.  It has always done this with every installation I've ever had on every computer I've ever installed it on.  Outlook 2010, on the other hand, has never done this.  I am thinking that maybe they "fixed" this in Outlook 2010, but part of me also hopes that there's some way to keep this from happening in Outlook 2007.  Essentially, I don't want the email address of the account I am using to reply to all to show in the recipient list.

Answer (score 2):

"...sometimes Outlook sends an email to yourself when you hit the 'Reply All' button.
This VBA example checks the list of recipients before sending, and it removes certain addresses from it.

http://www.vboffice.net/sample.html?mnu=2&smp=81&cmd=showitem&lang=en

```
Private Sub RemoveRecipients(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim RemoveThis As VBA.Collection
Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
Dim R As Outlook.Recipient
Dim i&, y&
Set RemoveThis = New VBA.Collection

' here add addresses
RemoveThis.Add "abc@domain.de"
RemoveThis.Add "test@domain.com"

Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set R = Recipients.Item(i)

    For y = 1 To RemoveThis.Count
        If LCase$(R.Address) = LCase$(RemoveThis(y)) Then
            Recipients.Remove i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
RemoveRecipients Item
End Sub
```

If you are unfamiliar with VBA see here http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/
Or
[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no way to automate this. You will have to remove your name each time.

Comment: This is so true if we're not talking about third-party solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this happening is that your email address in Account settings
is different from the one you reply with.

For more information when this can be happening, see the following articles,
also detailing procedures for avoiding it:

- [Reply All adds the sender's email address to the return message in Outlook for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2878894/reply-all-adds-the-sender-s-email-address-to-the-return-message-in-out)
- [Reply to All Includes My Address](https://www.slipstick.com/problems/reply-to-all-includes-my-address/)
- [When I reply to all, my e-mail address is on the TO field](http://www.aurelp.com/2013/01/16/when-i-reply-to-all-my-e-mail-address-is-on-the-to-field-outlook-2010/)

If you cannot find your answer above, the free utility
[TuneReplyAll](http://ivasoft.com/tunereplyall.shtml)
could help, where you may specify Outlook's behavior:

[image: TuneReplyAll settings]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of users here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/reply-to-all-includes-me/a227f787-594c-495b-8290-4105c453eaaa?auth=1 experienced the same issue, where they had added their own e-mail address as a contact in Outlook, which was the cause for them.
Once they removed themselves from their individual contact book it stopped happening.

Comment: If the link dies this answer becomes meaningless. It's best to copy the relevant part and add a link to the website

Answer (score 0):

Because Office 2007 is [no longer supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3198497/office-2007-approaching-end-of-extended-support) by Microsoft and therefore not receiving security patches of any sort, it's not inappropriate to suggest upgrading to a modern, secure version of Outlook.

Not only will such an upgrade solve the irritating problem that has prompted this question, it will also solve the much more dangerous issue of running insecure software that comes into contact with untrusted content delivered straight from the Internet, *otherwise known as e-mail*.